# How can I produce github annotations by creating report files on disk?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-api, lint

I am trying to find a portable way to produce [code annotations for GitHub](https://github.community/t/what-are-annotations/16173/2) in a way that would avoid a vendor-lockin.

Mainly I want to dump annotations inside a file (yaml, json,...) during build process and have a task at the end that does transform this file into github annotations.

The main goal here is to avoid hardcoding support for github-annotation into the tools that produce them, so other CI/CD systems could also consume the annotation-reports and display them in their UI.

```
linters -> annotations.report -> github-upload
```

Tools like flake8 are able to produce output in parsable format `file:line:column: message`, but I need to know if there is any attempt to standardize annotations so we can collect and combine them from multiple tools and feed them to the CI/CD engine.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using https://github.com/yuzutech/annotations-action
Sample action code:

```yaml
      - name: Annotate
        uses: yuzutech/annotations-action@v0.3.0
        with:
          repo-token: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
          input: ./annotations.json
          title: 'Findings'
          ignore-missing-file: true
```

It does its job well but with one minor defect. If you have a findings on a commit/PR you get to see the finding with a beautiful annotation right where you need it. If you re-push changes, even if the finding persists, the annotation is not displayed on later commits. I have opened an issue but I have not yet received an answer.

The `annotations-action` mentioned above has not been updated and it does not work with me at all (deprecated calls).

I haven't found anything else that worked exactly as I wanted it to.

Update: I found that you can use reviewdog to annotate based on findings. I also created a GitHub action that can be used for Static Code Analysis here https://github.com/tsigouris007/action-semgrep-reviewdog. You can visit the `entrypoint.sh` file and check how I piped the custom output to reviewdog utilizing `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Today I googled up what the heck those "Github Action Annotations" are all, and this was among the hits:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/annotations-action

> GitHub action for creating annotations from JSON file

As of now that page also contains:

> This repository uses npm packages from @attest scope on github; we are working hard to open source these packages.

> Annotations Action is not certified by GitHub. It is provided by a third-party and is governed by separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support documentation.

I didn't try it, again, just a random google hit.